# How to deserialize Array vb.net

Tags: xml, arrays, vb.net

I am currently writing an IRC Bot. I want to have information commands that are read from an XML file. I have an array the following class:

```
Public Class IrcCommand
    Public IsEnabled As Boolean
    Public Command As String
    Public Userlevel As Integer
    Public Message As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal e As Boolean, ByVal c As String, ByVal u As Integer, ByVal m As String)
        Me.IsEnabled = e
        Me.Command = c
        Me.Userlevel = u
        Me.Message = m
    End Sub
End Class
```

I already have the code to serialize this

```
Dim commands(2) As Command
commands(0) = New Command(True, "!test1", 0, "Hello there.")
commands(1) = New Command(True, "!test2", 0, "Test2")
commands(2) = New Command(True, "!test3", 0, "Test3")
```

into the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<commands>
  <command IsEnabled="True" Command="!test1" Userlevel="0">Hello there.</command>
  <command IsEnabled="True" Command="!test2" Userlevel="0">Test2</command>
  <command IsEnabled="True" Command="!test3" Userlevel="0">Test3</command>
</commands>
```

But I have no idea how to deserialize it so I get back the input array.
I've been searching the internet for the last 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("test.xml")
        Dim command As New Command(True, String.Empty, 0, String.Empty)
        Dim commands As New List(Of Command)

        Do While (reader.Read())
            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Element
                    If reader.Name = "command" Then
                        command = New Command(True, String.Empty, 0, String.Empty)
                        While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
                            If reader.Name = "IsEnabled" Then
                                command.IsEnabled = CBool(reader.Value)
                            ElseIf reader.Name = "Userlevel" Then
                                command.Userlevel = CInt(reader.Value)
                            ElseIf reader.Name = "Command" Then
                                command.Command = reader.Value
                            End If
                        End While
                    End If
                Case XmlNodeType.Text
                    command.Message = reader.Value
                    commands.Add(command)
            End Select
        Loop
        output(commands)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub output(c As List(Of Command))
        For Each command As Command In c
            Console.Write("<command")
            Console.Write(" IsEnabled=""" & CStr(command.IsEnabled) & """")
            Console.Write(" Command=""" & command.Command & """")
            Console.Write(" Userlevel=""" & CStr(command.Userlevel) & """>")
            Console.Write(command.Message)
            Console.WriteLine("</command>")
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

This is the mess I have sofar...

Comment: Very unclear what the hang-up might be.  You just don't know how to cast the return value of XmlSerializer.Deserialize() properly?  Post what you've tried to make work.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [HOW TO: Serialize and Deserialize XML in Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730/EN-US) :)

Comment: @Neolisk I actually tried that exact resource. I actually am capable of using Google myself. Based on that I did make somethng but its awful and doesnt work very well.

Comment: You need to stop being offensive and *actually* post your efforts above.

Comment: @Neolisk Wasn't intending to be offensive an yeah, I edited

Comment: @TBotV63: You are doing serialization manually here. The article I posted in the comment above suggests a way to do serialization **automatically** with 2-3 lines of code (so there is no need for `Dim reader As XmlTextReader` and such), using special attributes. Please go through the article again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a head start (tested and working in VS 2013 - writes okay). For reading, refer to this article:

- [HOW TO: Serialize and Deserialize XML in Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730/EN-US)

I gotta run now, if you have any questions regarding this implementation or you cannot make it read your class back, please let me know in comments.

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim commandList As New IrcCommandList
    commandList.Commands.Add(New IrcCommand(True, "!test1", 0, "Hello there."))
    commandList.Commands.Add(New IrcCommand(True, "!test2", 0, "Test2"))
    commandList.Commands.Add(New IrcCommand(True, "!test3", 0, "Test3"))

    Using objStreamWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\1\commands.xml")
      Dim x As New XmlSerializer(GetType(IrcCommandList))
      x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, commandList)
    End Using
  End Sub

End Module

<Serializable>
Public Class IrcCommand
  <XmlAttribute>
  Public IsEnabled As Boolean
  <XmlAttribute>
  Public Command As String
  <XmlAttribute>
  Public Userlevel As Integer
  <XmlText>
  Public Message As String

  'default constructor is required for serializable classes
  Public Sub New()
  End Sub

  Public Sub New(ByVal e As Boolean, ByVal c As String, ByVal u As Integer, ByVal m As String)
    Me.IsEnabled = e
    Me.Command = c
    Me.Userlevel = u
    Me.Message = m
  End Sub
End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class IrcCommandList
  <XmlArray("commands"), XmlArrayItem("command", GetType(IrcCommand))>
  Public Property Commands As New List(Of IrcCommand)

  'default constructor is required for serializable classes
  Public Sub New()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Output (very close to what you need, may need some additional tweaking):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<IrcCommandList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <commands>
    <command Userlevel="0" Command="!test1" IsEnabled="true">Hello there.</command>
    <command Userlevel="0" Command="!test2" IsEnabled="true">Test2</command>
    <command Userlevel="0" Command="!test3" IsEnabled="true">Test3</command>
  </commands>
</IrcCommandList>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. The hang up was pretty much that I didn't now how to serialize attribute looking at it now. I can deal with the document being slightly different :)