# Deserializing with multiple sub tags in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, datagridview

Hi all I am new here I have an invoiceList xml file that I need to deserialize I won't have any control over the elements to change them as I will be getting it from an external source.

the sample invoice is like so

```
<InvoicesList type="Invoices" date="17-11-2011" customerid="999999" version="1.0">

<invoice>
<number>9123123123</number>
<custid>999999</custid>
<custname>Your Company Name</custname>
<date>2011-11-15T00:00:00</date>
<vessel></vessel>
<saildate>2011-11-15T00:00:00</saildate>
<manifestref>HD56448/61</manifestref>
<reference>00</reference>
<customerref>2331748</customerref>

</invoice>

<invoice>
<number>9259854525</number>
<custid>999999</custid>
<custname>Your Company Name</custname>
<date>2011-11-15T00:00:00</date>
<manifestref>HD56448/61</manifestref>
<reference>00</reference>
<customerref>2331748</customerref>
<weight>0000000000</weight>
<length>0000000013</length>
<paymentdue>452.65</paymentdue>
<icgvatno>IE 123123123J</icgvatno>
<custvatno>IE 321321321J</custvatno>
</invoice>
</InvoicesList>
```

I have a InvoicesList class which just has the property for invoice with get and set 
then i have invoice class that has all the properties required,

now I can deserialize the first invoice no problem and display it in a datagridview on windows forms application but can't seem to get the other one to go into it, my deserializtion code is as follows

```
Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(filepath) 'Path where file is
        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(GetType(InvoicesList))
        O = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)  'O is reference as object of invoicesList
        objStreamReader.Close()
        Dim Invoices As New List(Of invoice)
        Invoices.Add(CType(O, InvoicesList).invoice)
        Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = Invoices
```

What I want is for the second invoice to go onto the next row of the datagridview there could be multiple invoices in the invoicesList so I know a for loop would be best,
Hope you can help. If any things else is needed please let me know.
I know the elements in both are different I just cut out a lot of them to save space.

here is my invoice class again I cut out alot of properties to save room

```
Public Class invoice
Private numberProperty As String
Private custidProperty As String
Private custnameProperty As String
Private routeProperty As String
Private manifestrefProperty As String
Private referenceProperty As String
Private customerrefProperty As String
Private weightProperty As String
Private lengthProperty As String
Private vehicleregProperty As String
Private unitProperty As String
Private unittypeProperty As String
Private goodsProperty As String
Private paymentdueProperty As Decimal
Private icgvatnoProperty As String
Private custvatnoProperty As String


Public Property number As String
    Get
        Return numberProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        numberProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property custid As String
    Get
        Return custidProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        custidProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property custname As String
    Get
        Return custnameProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        custnameProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property unittype As String
    Get
        Return unittypeProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        unittypeProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property goods As String
    Get
        Return goodsProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        goodsProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property sparedesc2 As String
    Get
        Return sparedesc2Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sparedesc2Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property sparedesc3 As String
    Get
        Return sparedesc3Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sparedesc3Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property sparedesc4 As String
    Get
        Return sparedesc4Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sparedesc4Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property channelbookingamount As Decimal
    Get
        Return ChannelbookingamountProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        ChannelbookingamountProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property vatamount As Decimal
    Get
        Return vatamountProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        vatamountProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property spareamount5 As Decimal
    Get
        Return spareamount5Property
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        spareamount5Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property driver1 As String
    Get
        Return driver1Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        driver1Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property driver2 As String
    Get
        Return driver2Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        driver2Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property driver3 As String
    Get
        Return driver3Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        driver3Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property driver4 As String
    Get
        Return driver4Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        driver4Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property driver5 As String
    Get
        Return driver5Property
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        driver5Property = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property abnormalload As String
    Get
        Return abnormalloadProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        abnormalloadProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property paymentdue As Decimal
    Get
        Return paymentdueProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        paymentdueProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property icgvatno As String
    Get
        Return icgvatnoProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        icgvatnoProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property custvatno As String
    Get
        Return custvatnoProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        custvatnoProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
End class
```

I then have my invoicesList class

```
Public Class InvoicesList
Private InvoiceProperty As invoice
Public Property invoice As invoice
    Get
        Return InvoiceProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As invoice)
        InvoiceProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
End class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deserialize Array vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225703/how-to-deserialize-array-vb-net)

Comment: Check my answer to it, in your case just remove attributes from the properties and the will be serialized as nodes (default behavior).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more I looked at the other link and I'm still a bit lost. Sorry I'm very new to serializing

Comment: Please edit your question and add your invoice class definition there.

Comment: Have you any clue where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sorry I've been busy for the whole day at work today. I will reply as soon as I have a spare minute. Off top of my head, you are missing <Serializable> attribute on your class. Also, serializable classes need a default constructor.

Comment: thanks for the advice I've added in the constructor and <serialzed>
I can deserialize one invoice no problem with the code above I just don't know how to add the next invoice into the next row in the datagridview

Comment: Ok hold on, you are saying you deserialize the whole list just fine, and your problem is about adding a row to the datagridview? Or you deserialize one row only, and now you need to deserialize the second row and also add it to the grid? In which case your problem would be deserializing InvoicesList correctly (instead of doing invoice one by one). Please confirm.

Comment: Yes when I run the code above the first invoice will go into the datagrid view but only the first invoice I want the second invoice to go into a new row on the datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only storing one invoice in the list (see your .NET class), that's why it was reading only one item. Changing it to inherit from a generic list is one way to do it (which I think is most simple to explain).

Using your XML without modifications, change your `InvoicesList` class to the following:

```
Public Class InvoicesList : Inherits List(Of invoice)
End Class
```

Then your deserialization process to this:

```
Dim O As InvoicesList
Using objStreamReader As New StreamReader(filePath)
  Dim x As New XmlSerializer(GetType(InvoicesList), New XmlRootAttribute("InvoicesList"))
  O = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
End Using
```

Notice the trick here - second parameter for XmlSerializer, [the approach is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562415/xml-deserialization-generic-method).

You do not need to add **serializable** attribute to the class, which I originally expected to be a requirement for deserialization to work. The rest should be good to go.

Comment: Hi Neolisk Just one more question with the new classes changed to your recommendations above. how would you go about setting the invoice properties and serializing it? for example I have a BOOKING class that has a Property that's called message and said message property holds more properties I was able to serialize them but unable to deserialize but now using your code I can deserialize but not serialize the BOOKING Class

Comment: @user3589647: To be inline with StackOverflow guidelines, if you have another question, please ask a separate question. Provide all relevant information in it. You can link this question from it, if you want. Then leave a comment here, I'll have a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491519/serializing-when-class-inherits-list-of-object

Here's the other question.

Comment: @user3589647: But you already have an answer on that. Please ask a new question where you would only list the information that is relevant to your new issue.

Comment: Sorry new question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522671/serializing-while-class-inherits-list-of-another-class